# except block is not working in try except in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-lambda, amazon-eks

I am trying to get list of pods from specific namespace in aws lambda (python).

Its giving right and expected list of pods. But When I pass wrong namespace, it is not skipping the try block and not catching the except block to return the correct response. Any reason for this ?

```
import json
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException

def get_pods(namespace: str, apiCoreclient: object):

    response_output = {}
    response_output["statusCode"] = 200    

    retList = []
    items = apiCoreclient.list_namespaced_pod(namespace).items
    for item in items:
        try:
            retList.append(item.metadata.name)
            response_output['Pods'] = json.dumps({"Pods": retList})

        except ApiException as e:
            response_output["error"] = e.reason
            response_output["statusCode"] = e.status

    response_output["isBase64Encoded"] = "False"       
    return json.dumps(response_output)
```

Comment: possibly `items` is an empty list so the `for` loop was never entered.

Comment: The "except ApiException as e:" block will only be ran if an ApiException is thrown in the "try:" block. Are you sure the 2 lines in the "try" block has a possibility of throwing an ApiException?

Comment: If you want to catch errors for an invalid/wrong namespace, you might want to surround the "items = apiCoreclient.list_namespaced_pod(namespace).items" in a try block instead, and catch the appropriate exception that will be thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be tied to the location of your `try/except` error handling.
In your current code, you've placed the `try/except` inside the loop that goes through each item. This means that it only catches errors when you're adding the pod name to the `retList` or setting the 'Pods' field in the `response_output`.

But the error you're anticipating - an `ApiException` - would probably occur when you attempt to list the pods in the namespace with `apiCoreclient.list_namespaced_pod(namespace)`. This line is outside your `try/except` block, so if an `ApiException` happens there, it's not going to be caught by your error handling.

To remedy this, you should shift your `try/except` block to encompass the `apiCoreclient.list_namespaced_pod(namespace)` line. Here's a tweaked version of your function to illustrate this:

```
def get_pods(namespace: str, apiCoreclient: object):
    response_output = {}
    response_output["statusCode"] = 200    
    retList = []

    try:
        items = apiCoreclient.list_namespaced_pod(namespace).items
        for item in items:
            retList.append(item.metadata.name)
        response_output['Pods'] = json.dumps({"Pods": retList})

    except ApiException as e:
        response_output["error"] = e.reason
        response_output["statusCode"] = e.status

    response_output["isBase64Encoded"] = "False"       
    return json.dumps(response_output)
```

In this refined version, if an `ApiException` arises when you try to list the pods in the namespace, it will be caught and the correct error response will be created.